# Vue.js - Drilldown highmaps

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

Olá, estou tentando criar um Mapa com Drilldown igual do link abaixo:
https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/map-drilldown
porem no Vue.js, e não achei nada sobre isso para o Vue.js, alguém já realizou algo parecido?
preciso de um exemplo.

Obrigada

Comment: já tentou o [vue-highcharts](https://github.com/weizhenye/vue-highcharts)

Comment: Sim, é com ele que crio meus gráficos e Mapas, porem preciso implementar o drilldown junto com meu mapa e não achei nenhum exemplo disso.